# What are limits on installing my iOS app on different devices?

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, installation

Say, I have an opensource application that I share on GitHub and which is easily can be compiled with XCode and installed on a user's device.

I share an app, then users download the source code, compile it and transfer to their devices.

Are there any limits on how they can use the application? I read there is a 30-days limits for installing ad hoc apps.

Does this or other limits apply for the apps that are compiled by a user and installed on their own device?

Answer (score 0):

The user who downloads and installs the app will be using their own Apple developer account and will be limited to the 30-day limit for ad hoc installations.